# I want to display date as date, month and year in seperate text boxes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change the text of all the classes of customerRequiredDate id.  I am trying it in this way, but its not setting day, month and year in the different text boxes.

```
customerRequiredDate=calcdate(5);
day=customerRequiredDate.substr(8,2);
month=customerRequiredDate.substr(5,2);
year=customerRequiredDate.substr(0,4);

$('#customerRequiredDate > .da_day').text(day);
$('#customerRequiredDate > .da_month').text(month);
$('#customerRequiredDate > .da_year').text(year);

function calcdate(leaddays) {

    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var c = 1;

    for (var i =0; i<leaddays; i++) {
        var nd = new Date();
        nd.setMonth(nd.getMonth());
        nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + c);
        var mn = nd.getMonth()+1;
        var dy = nd.getDate();
        var yy = nd.getFullYear();
        var day = nd.getDay();
        c++;
        if (( day == 0) || (day == 6)) {  // omit Sun and Sat
            i--;
        }
        else {
            if(dy<10) {
                dy="0" +dy;
            }

            if(mn<10) {
                mn="0" +mn;
            }

            var d = yy + "/" + mn+ "/" + dy;
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

my HTML is:

```
<tr>
    <td class="column-data" id="customerRequiredDate">
        Customer Required Date:
    </td>
    <td class="column-data">
        <input type="text" name="day"   class="da_day"  value="{$da_day}"   size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="month" class="da_month"  value="{$da_month}" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="year"  class="da_year"  value="{$da_year}"  size="4"/>
        (dd-mm-yyyy)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML too.

Comment: Please share the `calcdate` function as well.

Comment: HTML is<tr>
                <td class="column-data" id="customerRequiredDate">
                    Customer Required Date:
                </td>
                <td class="column-data">
                    <input type="text" name="day"   class="da_day"  value="{$da_day}"   size="2"/>
                    <input type="text" name="month" class="da_month"  value="{$da_month}" size="2"/>
                    <input type="text" name="year"  class="da_year"  value="{$da_year}"  size="4"/>
                    (dd-mm-yyyy)
                </td>
            </tr>

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `>` selector, which specifies the immediate child.  `customerRequiredDate` does not have any children, so it will not work.

For the element structure you have, you need something similar to the following:

```
$('#customerRequiredDate').next('td').find(".da_day").val(day);
$('#customerRequiredDate').next('td').find(".da_month").val(month);
$('#customerRequiredDate').next('td').find(".da_year").val(year);
```

I've tried to keep this a simple as possible, as it is clear (no offense) that you aren't familiar with how selectors work, so you can refer to the jQuery documentation and very easily learn how `.next()` and .`find()` work in this.

An example of more advanced selectors would be:

```
$('#customerRequiredDate + td > .da_day').val(day);
$('#customerRequiredDate + td > .da_month').val(month);
$('#customerRequiredDate + td > .da_year').val(year);
```

The `+` indicates the following element, so it's getting the element(s) with the specified class, that is a direct child of a TD, which follows `#customerRequiredDate`.

And lastly, since the elements you are changing are inputs, you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: I was about the recommend that second selector but you beat me to it. This is the better answer. Also, I checked out their date parsing and it works fine. There were a few improvements that could be made though.

Answer (score 1):

I will only dive into the issues that are directly causing the problem you describe. It is worth mentioning, though, that you should avoid manual gyrations for date calculations/parsing/formatting as much as possible and stick to built in language features and well tested libraries.

**Issue 1:**

Your selectors are not finding your inputs. The selector, `#customerRequiredDate > .da_day`, finds an element with class `da_day` that is a direct child of an element with ID `customerRequiredDate`. The elements you're hoping to change are not children of the element with ID `customerRequiredDate`. There are various ways you could adjust the markup and selectors to find the specific element you want, but in my modifications to your code (below), I've simply given the `td` that *does* contain the inputs an ID of `customerRequiredDateInputs` and changed the selectors in the JS to use it. *(IMO, It would be best to give your `input` elements IDs and directly target them.)*

**Issue 2:**

To change the value of input, you need to use `.val()` as opposed to `.text()`

**Modified Code:**

```js
customerRequiredDate=calcdate(5);
day=customerRequiredDate.substr(8,2);
month=customerRequiredDate.substr(5,2);
year=customerRequiredDate.substr(0,4);

$('#customerRequiredDateInputs > .da_day').val(day);
$('#customerRequiredDateInputs > .da_month').val(month);
$('#customerRequiredDateInputs > .da_year').val(year);

function calcdate(leaddays) {

    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var c = 1;

    for (var i =0; i<leaddays; i++) {
        var nd = new Date();
        nd.setMonth(nd.getMonth());
        nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + c);
        var mn = nd.getMonth()+1;
        var dy = nd.getDate();
        var yy = nd.getFullYear();
        var day = nd.getDay();
        c++;
        if (( day == 0) || (day == 6)) {  // omit Sun and Sat
            i--;
        }
        else {
            if(dy<10) {
                dy="0" +dy;
            }

            if(mn<10) {
                mn="0" +mn;
            }

            var d = yy + "/" + mn+ "/" + dy;
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column-data" id="customerRequiredDate">
            Customer Required Date:
        </td>
        <td class="column-data" id="customerRequiredDateInputs">
            <input type="text" name="day"   class="da_day"  value=""   size="2"/>
            <input type="text" name="month" class="da_month"  value="" size="2"/>
            <input type="text" name="year"  class="da_year"  value=""  size="4"/>
            (dd-mm-yyyy)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```